# how to use stripes framework with angular

Tags: angular, stripes

We are migrating one of our legacy projects to angular. For some unavoidable reasons we have to use [stripesframework](https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/STRIPES/overview) as the backend framework.
How can I use angular `HttpClient` services along with stripes' `@HandlesEvents` events

Comment: Can you enlighten us as to what stripes is, and what the problem is with using HttpClient

Comment: Getting a bit long in the tooth https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/STRIPES/overview

Comment: see https://stripesframework.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/STRIPES/pages/53379776/Read+JSON+Requests+with+Stripes+1.5

Comment: updated the issue with link ;)

Comment: You should really question the use of that framework - it has not seen a single new release since mid 2015...

Comment: It seems that REST was supposed to be added in v1.7 - but latest release is 1.6, so there doesn't seem to be a simple method of calling the services. You have to use the stripes JavaScript client - which might not have TypeScript bindings.